# Change countif range using vba

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, countif

I would like to change the range in the counfif-formula by using vba. By clicking a button the Range A3:A3 changes to A3:A4, then clicking the button again A3:A4 changes to A3:A5, and so on... I managed to create a constant vba-formula, but I do not know how to proceed. Anybody? :)

[Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VT8A.png)

[VBA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IorDR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a dummy cell/value to achieve, The dummy cell will "count" how many times you have clicked the button. My solution will require a dummy cell.

```
Sub Countif_function()
Dim start_value As Long

start_value = Cells(1, "D").Value 'Take the value from cell D1
If start_value <= 3 Or Cells(1, "D").Value = "" Then start_value = 3 ' If the value is less than 3 (since you start at row 3) or if the value is empty then set the minimum start value to 3 (otherwise countif will fail).

Cells(3, "D").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.countif(Range(Cells(3, "A"), Cells(start_value, "A")), "A") 'Using the inbuild function in VBA to retrieve the countif
Cells(3, "E").Value = "=COUNTIF(A3:A" & start_value & ",""A"")" 'Just for view purpose of the final formula result, can be ignored in the code
Cells(1, "D").Value = Cells(1, "D").Value + 1 'Add +1 row. This will be used as the start value for next time the code is executed.

End Sub
```

I used "A" as criteria since you used it in your example code, but could be change to "C3" or some other cell.

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The alternate if you don't want a dummy cell to count as per the previous answer is to read the formula in the cell into a string variable via range.formula, split it on the comma, read the last digit of the first entry in the split array, increment by 1.  (If the digit is a 9, then check whether the preceding character is a number or letter, if letter, make the 9 a 10, if number, increment that by one and make the 9 a 0, if the preceding character is also a 9, recursive call).  So, yeah, unless you really cannot have the dummy cell, use that solution, it's easier.